# Command line arguments with keywords

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I am passing the command line arguments to a Perl script and retrieving it via `ARGS[0]`.

```
perl <perlscript.pl> windows IE.
```

I would like to give keywords to the values mentioned above.

```
perl <perlscript.pl> -os windows -browser IE -instance 2.
```

There might be times where `instance` might or might not be present. How do I go about handling this in my Perl script?

Answer (score 6):

Use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) and store your options in a hash:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my %opt;
GetOptions(\%opt, qw(
    os=s
    browser=s
    instance=i
)) or die;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several modules for handling command line arguments: [`Getopt::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/~fangly/Getopt-Declare-1.14/lib/Getopt/Declare.pm) and [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) are probably the most popular. At my work we mainly use Getopt::Declare so Ill show and example of that since @toolic covered Getopt::Long.

```
my $ARGS = Getopt::Declare->new(
   join("\n", 
        "[strict]",
        "-os       <string> The operating system [required]",
        "-browser  <string> The web browser      [required]",
        "-instance <int>    The instance"
   ) 
) or die;
```

Now you can access any of the parmeters via the `$ARGS` hash. i.e. `$ARGS->{-os}`

`[strict]` parses the command line *strictly* and reports any errors.

`[required]` after an option declaration means that field must be there, note I left it off of instance.